# What is the meaning of the term בוחן כליות in High Holiday prayers?

Tags: song-poetry, musaf, high-holidays

In Nusach Ashkenaz (and I assume Nusach Sefard as well as other *nuscha'ot*), there is a "hymn" said as part of the *Musaph* service on both days of Rosh Hashanna and Yom Kippur that has a refrain וכל מאמינים (Everyone believes).

One of the phrases says:
וכל מאמינים שהוא בוחן כליות

Translating literally:

"Everyone believes that He (G-d) checks the kidneys"

I assume that the term בוחן כליות is a metaphor for "a person's intentions or thoughts". But, I am trying to get a sense that if that is what is meant, what is the connection of mentioning the kidneys and what does it mean to "check" or "investigate" them. Investigate what?

Comment: @GershonGold **possibly**, as you said. The metaphor may be similar, but, Hashem is a better doctor and biologist than you or I to know if these two parts of the body do similar actions, so to speak :-)

Comment: Chazal famously believed that the kidneys contribute to thought (Cf. Berachos 61a). Accordingly, the connection to thought is perfectly clear.

Comment: Very similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56733

Comment: @msh210 Thanks. I flagged for moderator assist on this. Since you are a diamond-guy, please refer to what I mentioned, there.

Comment: This is not a duplicate as worded, but I'm closing as duplicate because of what was mentioned in the aforementioned flag.

Comment: @msh210 Thanks. I'll try to edit a bit later. Shanah Tovah