Does Binah come from the heart or brain - Birkat Ahavat Olam
In the morning prayer in birkat Ahavat Olam /Ahava Rabbah we say

וְתֵן בְּלִבֵּֽנוּ בִּינָה לְהָבִין וּלְהַשְׂכִּיל לִשְׁמֹֽעַ לִלְמוֹד וּלְ֒לַמֵּד


put into our hearts [comprehension] to understand and to be intellectually creative, to listen, to learn...

Why are we asking for Hashem to put Binah in our "hearts" shouldn't we ask for it to be put into our "brain -שכל", as this is the organ we use to think and use our intellect?

In Torah, the heart is the organ we use to think (בכונת הלב - same gematria as תפלה; see also חובות הלבבות שער חשבון הנפש ג׳ - the 9th principle), but you are asking a good question because it is not the organ that houses our בינה and other intellectual faculties. I think the answer might come from along these lines. +1

In the language of Tanach and Chazal, לב is the seat of thoughts. See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27008/why-the-brain-moach-as-the-source-for-thought-is-not-mentioned-in-torah,   https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85468/why-is-the-heart-labeled-the-seat-of-emotion

@IsaacMoses the question is about בינה, not thought

@RabbiKaii I meant "thoughts" as generally as possible - all internal processing. In fact, I suspect that that sense of לב is much stronger than that of an anatomical muscle in the chest; I'm sure there are some examples of the latter in Tanach, but I'm struggling to think of them.

@IsaacMoses I am agreeing with the fact that it is not an anatomical muscle in the chest, and even with that in mind, generally speaking there is a strong difference between the lev and sechel. The question is good because Binah is a faculty of sechel, not lev. Thoughts are akin to action involving intellect, Binah is more "the stuff of which intellect is made"

בינה לבא ובה הלב מבין

+1. Note, Ashkenaz don't say בינה; just ותן בלבנו להבין ולהשכיל.

The רסיסי לילה asks and answers this exact question י״ב:א:

תפלה עיקרה בלב כמו שאמרו (תענית ב.) עבודה שהיא בלב כו' זו תפלה וכן
המתפלל צריך שיכוין את לבו (ברכות לא.) וטובא. ותורה כפי הנראה עיקרה
במוח אבל אנו מבקשים ותן בלבנו בינה וגו' כידוע דיש חכמה ובינה שהם מוחא
ולבא. פירוש חכמה הוא כללי דברי תורה המפורשים ובינה הוא התבוננות דבר
מתוך דבר המפורש לדון ולהורות בשעת מעשה1
Prayer's main mode is with concentration of the heart, as it says in
Taanit 2a: "Divine Service means [service of the] heart etc.", and
this is prayer. When one prays, one needs to concentrate his heart
(Berachot 31a). Torah study's main mode, on the other hand, is with
the brain, yet we ask "place Binah into our hearts etc". As we know,
there is Chochma and Binah, which correspond to the brain and the
heart respectively. An explanation is that Chochma is the general
grasp of the matters of Torah, and Binah is the contemplation of the
concrete understanding of the practical implications within these
matters as they pertain to how to implement them in our actions.1

So, even if we say that Binah is an intellectual faculty, the way we use it is through contemplation and thought, which is a power of the heart. Torah Ohr Vayetzei 5:7 makes this point directly:

ותן בלבנו בינה כו'  שכדי להיות לבבנו מכון וכסא להשראת בינה ודעת
בבחי' הרגשה בלב הוא ע"י הרחמנות כי הרחמנות והדעת תלוי זה בזה.'
In order for our hearts to be a seat and centre for the inspiration
of Binah and Daat, on the level of feeling of the heart, it needs to
be acheived through compassion, as compassion and Daat are dependant on
each other

tl;dr בינה is a faculty of the שכל, and we can make use of it by seating it within our לבבנו, where we have tools to use it: thought and contemplation. This is why Binah is sometimes paired with the לב, and Chochma is paired with the שכל, even though truly they are both intellectual faculties.

1. Through refining one's character traits, and thereby distributing every fine quality to the limbs; to actuality. This happens through the "concentration of the heart" (as opposed to the "concentration of the mind") - Kol Hamaarich B'Echad 5690

Who is the author of רסיסי לילה

@Yoreinu צדוק הכהן מלובלין. Here is the full passage for your learning https://www.sefaria.org/Resisei_Layla.12.1?vhe=R%27_Zadok_--_Resisei_Layla&lang=he&with=About&lang2=he

Similar Torah Ohr Bereshit 1:2: "ותן בלבנו בינה שמבחינת רחמים עליונים נמשך בינה והתבוננות בלב להיות בה ועל ידה עשיית". Likkutei Torah Emor 3:11: "ולכן בקשתנו ברחמיך הרבים רחם עלינו ותן בלבנו בינה היינו להבין דבר מתוך דבר היינו אף בעוד שהנשמה מלובש בגוף יבין וישכיל שבאמת הכל בטל בתכלית כמו קודם שנברא העולם בלי שום שינוי ממש כנ״ל ולא נבוש לע״ו."

Okay, so there’s a difference between בינה and חכמה. So? What does this have to do with the question? Why is בינה usually attributed to the heart, not the brain?

@QwertyCTRL. I've hopefully made an edit that makes things clearer

Ah, I see now. +1

There is another Rav Tzadok that explains that binah which is inherently a women's middah is rooted in the heart whereas chochmah which is predominantly male is rooted in the brain.
