What is the thought of the heart?
In the prayer before the prayer תפילה קודם תפילה of Rabbi Elimelech of Lizansk, it appears: "And with our hearts when we think.עם ליבנו בעת מחשבותינו" Apparently, the thought is in the brain (In Hebrew, the first letters of the word "thought" מח אותיות ראשונות של מחשבה). The phrase "the thought of the heart" (מחשבת הלב) also appears in other places. And if so, how can the heart think, since thinking is done in the brain (who place Tefillin on the head to correct the thought)?

Actually, intellect is in the brain, thought itself is in the heart. How thought gets into the heart is sort of dealt with here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/143445/does-binah-come-from-the-heart-or-brain-birkat-ahavat-olam/143447#143447
