# "Chambers of the stomach" mentioned in Yom Kippur service

Tags: tefilla, yom-kippur, parts-of-the-body

There is a paragraph said just prior to the על חטא section of the Yom Kippur service that begins:

אתה חופש כל חדרי בטן

A (fairly) literal translation would be, "You search all the chambers of the stomach"

Since this paragraph introduces the lists of sins and is followed by a request that G-d forgive our sins, I assume that there is some connection between the stomach and sins. Why is that connection? What is G-d "searching" for in these chambers?

Comment: בטן is probably more like "gut" than "stomach". Unlike cows, humans don't have multi-chambered stomachs.

Comment: @DoubleAA humans don't have separate stomachs like cows. But the stomach does have "compartments" or "sections". Perhaps this is what is meant by the term חַדְרֵי.

Comment: The Arabic cognate seems very relevant--the word can have the sense of the interior of something, its depth, what is hidden and not revealed: https://books.google.ca/books?id=WTak55pG-_IC&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=batn

Comment: What with bochen kelayot valeva?

Comment: Chadrey are perhaps compartimento, peritoneale, extraperitoneal, digestive urinary

Comment: @kouty I'm aware of those. I have excluded them, intentionally, since I have found a suitable explanation for these. Regarding "betten", it may be a metaphor for "insides" (internals of the body). But, I think, since the same phrase mentions "klayot valev", I don't think it can be generalized in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31129/9643) will shed light on your question:

> The phrase, "חפש כל חדרי בטן" comes from [Proverbs
>   20:27](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2820.htm#27):
>
> > נר ה' נשמת אדם חפש כל חדרי בטן
> >
> > "The spirit of man is the lamp of the LORD, searching all the inward parts." (JPS 1917)
>
> The word, בטן, is often used simply to mean "belly" (and is therefore
>   associated with pregnancy), but in this context it means the innermost
>   aspects of the human being. Thus, ibn EZra understands it to refer to
>   the heart, writing "והוא רמז ללב שהוא חדר המחשבות" - "and this alludes
>   to the heart, which is the chamber of thoughts".

(*Credits: [LazerA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1216/lazera), [paquda](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1807/paquda)*)