Why Did the Torah Choose the Heart and Soul Over the Brain
Why did the Torah choose the heart and the soul Deuteronomy (Devarim) 11:18: "ושמתם את דברי אלה על לבבכם ועל נפשכם" ("And you shall set these words upon your hearts and upon your souls."), as the heart is an internal organ unaffected by the brain and operates on its own, and seemingly no one can influence it nearly, and the soul is an incomprehensible thing. So how can one place the words of G-d on these places, and why was the brain not chosen, which seemingly controls the person and the person has the ability to control it?

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27008/why-the-brain-moach-as-the-source-for-thought-is-not-mentioned-in-torah

We can raise our heart rate by running to do mitzvot.

Wow, a good one! It's hard to find new insights but you did it. The Torah consistently follows Cardiocentrism, i.e. the heart is the source of thought and intellect, e.g. "וְהִתְבָּרֵ֨ךְ בִּלְבָבֹ֤ו לֵאמֹר֙ שָׁלֹ֣ום יִֽהְיֶה־לִּ֔י". Aristotle famously held this view. However, Encephalocentrism, supported by Hippocrates and Plato became mainstream (at least in scientific circles) only by Galen in the 3rd century CE.

Now to the explanation: Judaism is, traditionally, an Orthopraxial religion, i.e. focused on ritual observance and rituals rather than faith and rationalism. While the Pharisees and later Rabbis adopted Hellenistic intellectualism and made Torah study a very important part of Jewish culture, it remained complimentary to everyday observance. In the passage you quote, the Torah stresses that it should first and foremost guide our practice.
